# Xdebug Failed loading C:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll

Tags: installation, xdebug

**Issue:**

I am getting this error in my Apache log on start up:

> Failed loading C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

**Xdebug Wizard:**

I used the xdebug wizard, which resulted in these instructions:

1. Download php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
2. Move the downloaded file to C:\php\ext
3. Edit C:\php\php.ini C:\WINDOWS\php.ini and add the line
4. zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
5. Restart the webserver

**Things I have tried:**

Using these variations in php.ini:

```
zend_extension="C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

I ensured I was editing correct php.ini file

I checked permissions on dll.

**I am using:**

- Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) VC 15
- php-7.4.3-Win32-vc15-x64
- php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

Comment: Solved! After running out of things to try, I re-downloaded php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll and noticed that the file size changed from 234kb to 266kb. Restarted Apache and all is well.

Comment: Check my answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76868782/12969125).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a release candidate of PHP 7.4.1 (`php-7.4.1RC1-Win32-vc15-x64`) - you might want to use the latest PHP 7.4.3.

You sometimes get a better error message if you try using PHP's command line.

Comment: Good catch. I updated to php-7.4.3-Win32-vc15-x64. Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.